# Heroku build log and logs showing no error but app doesn't run

Tags: heroku, discord.js

I have a discord.js bot hosted on Heroku connected to my GitHub repository
It works when I run it locally
and Heroku logs are not showing any error either but it isn't starting

```
2020-01-08T15:57:04.151726+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-01-08T15:57:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user ujjwalkandera23@gmail.com
2020-01-08T15:57:59.627953+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-01-08T15:57:59.154859+00:00 app[api]: Release v9 created by user ujjwalkandera23@gmail.com
2020-01-08T15:57:59.154859+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 85a9b9be by user ujjwalkandera23@gmail.com
2020-01-08T15:57:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-01-08T15:58:02.100811+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `: node bot.js`
2020-01-08T15:58:02.688922+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-01-08T15:58:04.452834+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-01-08T15:58:04.432152+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

Comment: Are you ever calling [`Client.login()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login) in your code?

Comment: Are you logging your errors anywhere?